# Find the cumulative distribution function of $M_{n} - m_{n}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Again, in this exercise how can I find the cumulative distribution function of $M_{n} - m_{n}$ and how I can calculate the limit in distribution of the sequence $(n (1 - M_{n} + m_{n})) \ n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Let $(U_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables i.i.d. with uniform distribution in the interval $[0, 1]$.
We define for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the random variables:
$$M_{n} = \max\{U_{1} ,...,U_{n}\}$$
$$m_{n} = \min\{U_{1} ,...,U_{n}\}$$

Show that $M_{n} -m_{n}\ \underrightarrow{d}\ 1$

Now I have to:

$$P(\min\{U_{1} ,...,U_{n}\}>a)=P(U_{1}>a)P(U_{2}>a)\dotsi P(U_{n}>a)=(1-a)^n$$
$$\rightarrow F_{m_{n}}(a)=1-(1-a)^n \rightarrow f_{m_{n}}(a)=n(1-a)^{n-1}$$

$$P(\max\{U_{1} ,...,U_{n}\}\leq a)=P(U_{1} \leq a)P(U_{2} \leq a)\dotsi P(U_{n} \leq a)=a^n$$
$$\rightarrow f_{m_{n}}(a)=na^{n-1}$$

I don't know how to continue, could you help me?

Comment: I tried to solve this, both $M_n,m_n$ are abs. continuous random variables. Let's denote $g(n) := F_{M_n} - F{m_n}, g \in [0,1]$ (maximum difference is 1, minimum is 0). Thus, $g(n) := a^n - (1 - (1-a)^n)$.  The problem is, if we integrate for $a \in [0,1]$, we get 0, so g(n) is not a cdf. I'm confused on where I messed up as well.

Comment: However, I'm fairly sure this is just an exercise on re-writing several random variables into a new random variable, so if someone can straighten out my $g(n)$ it should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use continuous mapping theorem:

$$m_n\xrightarrow{d}0$$

$$M_n\xrightarrow{d}1$$

Thus

$$M_n-m_n\xrightarrow{d}1$$

Comment: I think you meant to write 1? Besides doing this formally, if n is big enough, $M_n \xrightarrow{d} 1, m_n \xrightarrow{d} 0$, thus the difference should tend to 1.

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes: obviously...thanks for catching that (amended)